# Argocd works fine but WebUI fails to load data

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, argocd, traefik-ingress

I am facing a strange issue regarding my Argocd setup in my K8 cluster. I got installed argocd correctly and every pod is running fine. I am using traefik ingressroute to expose the argocd webui.

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: argocd-ingress
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`argocd.example.com`) && PathPrefix(`/`) 
      priority: 10
      services:
      - name: argo-cd-argocd-server
        port: 80
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`argocd.example.com`) && Headers(`Content-Type`, `application/grpc`)
      priority: 11
      services:
        - name: argo-cd-argocd-server
          port: 80
          scheme: h2c
  tls:                              
    secretName: tsl-secret
```

Let's say my domain is https://example.com and i am exposing argocd
on https://argocd.example.com.I've implemented the TLS secret correctly in my ingressroute. This is also an example ingressroute setup coming from Traefik Documentation itself.

The issue is: When i go to the url of my argocd (argocd.example.com), it opens up the argocd web page(completely empty page) but it gives an error:

```
"Failed to load data, please try again. Unable to load data, 404 page not found".
```

[image]

`Ps: This issue doesn't appear when i expose argocd via serviceType: "LoadBalancer"`

I've tried to upgrade the version of argocd,
redeployed the argocd deployments,
tried to re-implement traefik ingressroute CRD in different ways and many other things..
When i google this error i don't find anything helpful.

Maybe you guys have already experienced something similar and can guide how to troubleshoot this.

Thank you in advance !

- Tried to upgrade the Argocd version
- Redeployed argocd pods/deployments
- Restarted argocd-Redis pods many times
- Tried to access it in private browser (Chrome, Mozilla, Edge)
- Tried different ingressroute configs.
- Tried to recreate the argocd service and expose his ports.